# How to find hard drives by size or model?

Tags: shell, freebsd, disk

In FreeBSD, what is the correct way to find hard disk drives by some criteria, like size or model name (ok, here `/dev/disk/by-id` would help if one had it, as usually in Linux)?

For example in FreeBSD if we want to know all disks from Seagate Technology (= ST), one can do:

```
geom disk list | awk -v RS= '/descr: ST/ {print $3;}'
```

and similarly for disk capacity, searching for a 3-4 TB disk:

```
geom disk list | awk -v RS= '/Mediasize: .*(3..T)/ {print $3;}'
```

But is there a *clean* way to do it?

Comment: I guess you can scrape this info from various `/sys`files, but I'm not aware of a pre-made tool that gathers this information. There's `lsblk -O`, `lsscsi -v` etc., but I don't think one of them lists *everything* known about a HD.